# How to make .htaccess redirect olddomain.com/xyz to newdomain.com

Tags: .htaccess

I want to create a redirect via htaccess but not for my entire site, only for one page.

so while olddomain.com should work as normal I want to forward traffic on oldomain.com/xyz to newdomain.com

Answer (score 2):

Try below rule if work change to `R=301`,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/xyz
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com [R=302,L]
```